# SpringBoot Not recognizing java.lang

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I just started a Spring Starter Project, and I Got the following errors
[The Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMJ3Z.jpg) 
first Error says:

Multiple markers at this line

- The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .
  class files
- The type java.lang.Class cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .
  class files
- The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .
  class files
- The declared package "com.example.demo" does not match the expected package ""

Second Error Says:

Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

3rd Error Says:

String cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: have you done the maven update?

Comment: I downloaded the last version, 2.5.1 I think

Comment: I am using 
Maven 2.5.1
,SpringBoot 4
,eclipse 2021-6

Comment: Yeah, but have updated it. Like Right click project  -->  Maven --> Update Project. Try this once.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: Check your build path then Right Click Project --> Build Path--> Configure Build Path. It will show the java version which should be there. Let me know the JRE System Library version.

Comment: It was not using any JRE !!!!, I added jre 1.8, but it asked me to use 1.5, Why ?

Comment: It could be due to the maven version which is forcing the 1.5 version. But you can change the java version like Right Click Project  --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Java Compiler. Here you can change the java version.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate that, can you add an answer to the question so I can accept it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of errors can happen due to library issues. For solving it,

1. One can update the maven project first. It will be better to set a target java version like this inside properties tag in pom.xml.

> ```
> <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
> <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
> ```

2. One can configure the java version through eclipse by following step.

> Right Click Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Java
> Compiler